# Mechanize search unable to find CSS selector (it's definitely present)

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri, mechanize

I have a long CSS selector that works perfectly fine when actually used in CSS, jQuery etc. But this very same selector will not work on a `Mechanize::Page` object - it simply returns an empty array.

The selector targets a paragraph and in my other case a header1. I also converted my page result to string with `page.body`, and that element is definitely there, but the `search` (or `at`) method will not return me anything.

What could be the cause of this?

My code looks like this:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page  = agent.get 'http://example.com'

page.search(source.read_more_selector).each do |read_more|
  inner_page = agent.get(read_more['href'])
  # displaying inner_page.body gives me a few valid HTML pages, but...

  inner_page.search(source.inner_title_selector).each do |inner_content|
    # but here, there's nothing here, inner_content is nil even though the selector should get us something back definitely
  end
end
```

Normally working CSS selector (`source.inner_content_selector`)

```
div#main-container-body > div#body-container > table > tbody > tr > td > span#ajaxprochoice > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > h1.h1productHead
```

Output of `inner_page.body` (one of the many loop results. Can't be added here due to too many characters):

http://pastebin.com/MtXDVADR

So the above selector is supposed to definitely match the paragraph inside that HTML code (of course, while it's a `Mechanize::Page` object, not a string) with `inner_page.search`, but it's not.

I went to the actual page online and opened up my console and ran this simple jQuery command to try that out:

```
$('div#main-container-body > div#body-container > table > tbody > tr > td > span#ajaxprochoice > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > h1.h1productHead').hide();
```

And it worked! Which pretty much means the selector is valid here.

### Edit

When I added this piece of code:

```
inner_page.at('.h1productHead').to_s
```

This returned me a result. But when I use the full selector, it doesn't return anything. Why is Mechanize being inflexible with selectors in this case?

Comment: an html snippet and the actual selector would be nice.

Comment: I will put them here ASAP.

Comment: You assign the HTML to `page`, but then you are searching `inner_page`. It would also help to see the exact URL and CSS selector. Are you really looking at `example.com`?

Comment: As I mentioned, `inner_page` DOES return valid pages. I have analyzed them and they **do** include the results I am looking for with the very same selector, but it's failing to return something. The `read_more_selector` looks for `a` tags and takes their `href` attribute, then we use that to create the `inner_page`.  I will add the code samples soon - it was very late when I posted this.

Comment: @pguardiario Example code added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you are searching doesn’t contain any `tbody` tags. When your browser parses the page it adds the missing `tbody` elements into the DOM that it creates. This means that when you examine the page through the browser’s inspector and console it acts like the `tbody` tags exist.

Nokogiri doesn’t add this tag when parsing. When you use Nokogiri to search for your query (which contains `tbody`) it looks for an explicit `tbody` tag, and so returns no matches when it fails to find one.

The simplest fix is to remove all the `tbody`s from your query (along with any extra `>`s).

You could also look into [Nokogumbo](https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo), which extends Nokogiri with [Google’s Gumbo HTML5 parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser), and which does add the `tbody` elements into the parsed document.

Comment: When looking at the HTML prior to trying to find a node with code, I always dump the HTML to disk or directly into an editor and look at it without the browser. It's very convenient to use `nokogiri some_url` which will read the page and dump you into IRB with a populated `@doc` allowing you to nose around that way too. Doing these sort of things will immediately show that `tbody` doesn't exist and avoid that red-herring.

Answer (score 0):

One important tactic to learn when working with a DOM, is to locate the critical landmarks in the document and use those to navigate, rather than try to specify every tag seen from the top to the desired node. If you can use specific IDs or classes, go for those. If there is a particular pattern of nodes then they can be useful. Specifying every tag from A to B is error prone (as you saw) and often not necessary.

Instead of a selector like:

```
$('div#main-container-body > div#body-container > table > tbody > tr > td > span#ajaxprochoice > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > h1.h1productHead').hide();
```

You can try something like:

```
div#body-container span#ajaxprochoice table table table h1.h1productHead
```

and let libXML locate the desired end node.

You might even be able to reduce it to:

```
div#body-container h1.h1productHead
```

Since there can only be one `#body-container` in a well-formed HTML page, that would mean to find the `<h1 class="h1productHead">` under it. If there are multiples you can be more specific using a CSS index or by telling Nokogiri to get them all and then take the specific one you want, using either `search` or `at`.